# How to fix BLUETTOTH_SCAN permission with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, permissions, bluetooth-lowenergy, manifest, scanning

I'm on developing a flutter application contains a BLE module with flutter_blue package.
I tested it with android versions 8, 10 and 11 and it works but for android 12 I got an exception while scanning devices.
the exception is :
**E/flutter ( 8367): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(startScan, Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for android.content.AttributionSource@bbd118dc: GattService registerScanner, java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN **

this is the permissions on manifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES"
   android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
```

I would be very thankful if you can help me.

Comment: try by removing "android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" " in  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />  If it doesnt work I would recommend to use Permission package to get all permissions. You can do it by using FutureBuilder, that worked for me

Answer (score 3):

This is how I define permission in android
In `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<!-- required for API 18 - 30 -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

<!-- required for API 23 - 30 -->
<uses-permission-sdk-23
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

<!-- API 31+ -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
    android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
    tools:targetApi="s" />
```

And You have to ask permission runtime from user based on your needs, you can follow here [Android Bluetooth permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions)

```
if (androidApiVersion <= 30) {
  switch (await Permission.location.request()) {

  }
  return;
}

if (30 < androidApiVersion) {
  Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [Permission.bluetoothScan, Permission.bluetoothAdvertise].request();

  if (statuses[Permission.bluetoothScan] == PermissionStatus.granted && statuses[Permission.bluetoothScan] == PermissionStatus.granted) {
   // permission granted
  }
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these permissions.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

For FlutterBlue to function correctly on Android, these permissions are required (especially on newer Android versions).

Ensure that the user is granting location permission.

Use `https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler` and request for location permissions like in the snippet below before you start the scan.

`await Permission.location.request();`

Comment: This didn't make change.

Comment: Edited, give a try.

Comment: all those permissions are added and when I run the application I have a location permission popup. The problem accured when I scan devices

Comment: Change your package to flutter_blue_plus.

Comment: I'm on finishing the app. I was test an android 8 and 10 and it works fine .the problem occured with android 11. I shouldn't change package now

Comment: flutter_blue is very old and is not updated. The issue you have is most likely due to oudated flutter_blue. flutter_blue_plus is a forked version of flutter_blue, so you won't have to change much. I recommend you to just take a look. Anyway, do whatever suits your case best.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I tried with android 11 it worked that the problem is with android 12

Answer (score 0):

1)Delete the app from device and get build again. It solved for me when i was trying to access it.

2)Try to use permission_handler for permission to bluettoth.
https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler